# Почему при сборке webpack появляется ошибка связанная с babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel

При сборке проекта вебпак не хочет билдить js бандл, потому что не может найти модуль babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements. Вроде в package.json он прописан и устанавливается, но  ошибка есть:

> Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module
> 'babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements' from
> '/home/igor/Projects/amater'
>
> Did you mean "@babel/transform-react-constant-elements"?

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "amateur-react-webapp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && webpack --config=webpack.config.js -d --watch --display-error-details",
        "prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config=webpack.config.js --progress"
    },
    "scriptsComments": {
        "instruction": "First run npm install comand in order to instal necessary packages. Aftr that run npm run dev, or npm run prod to build app"
    },
    "author": "igor",
    "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-comments": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.4.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
        "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.6",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.5.2",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18",
        "compress-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.6",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "cssnano": "^4.0.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
        "flow-bin": "^0.86.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "react-outside-click-handler": "^1.3.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.7.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "schedule": "^0.4.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
        "webpack": "^3.12.0",
        "webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "^1.1.9"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.2.0",
        "body-scroll-lock": "^2.6.4",
        "core-js": "^3.2.1",
        "css-supports": "^0.1.1",
        "debounce": "^1.2.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
        "es7-object-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
        "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "object-polyfills": "^0.8.0",
        "primereact": "^1.3.0",
        "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "qrcode.react": "^1.0.0",
        "qs": "^6.8.0",
        "react": "16.5.2",
        "react-dom": "16.5.2",
        "react-props": "0.0.3",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "react-router": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "styled-components": "^4.1.1",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "ie 10",
        "not ie <= 9",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

конфиг webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CompressPlugin = require("compress-webpack-plugin");
const ASSETS_PATH = './assets';
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/build');


const webpack_config = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, ASSETS_PATH),

    entry: {
        main: [
            "promise-polyfill",
            "object-polyfills",
            "isomorphic-fetch",
            "core-js",
            "es7-object-polyfill",
            "babel-polyfill",
            "react",
            "react-dom",
            "react-props",
            "redux",
            "react-redux",
            "react-router",
        ],
        app       : "./js/index.js",
    },

    output: {
        filename: ("production" === process.env.NODE_ENV) ? 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].min.js' : 'js/[name].min.js',
        publicPath: '/public/build',
        path: BUILD_DIR
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [' ', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', 'css'],
    },

    devtool: ("production" === process.env.NODE_ENV) ? "source-map" : "eval-source-map",

    watchOptions: {
        poll: true
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?compact=true&comments=true&minified=true',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/react',
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                    ],
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [
                    /node_modules\/react-router-native/,
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/react',
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                    ],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '/fonts/'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.ico$|\.gif$|\.png$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 1024 * 10,
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: '/images/'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(
            [BUILD_DIR]
        ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: ' Amateur Webcams ',
            template: './html-templates/index.html',
            filename: '../../templates/index-tpl.html',
            chunks: ['main', 'app']
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './images/favicon',
                to: './images/favicon',
                toType: 'dir'
            }
        ]),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: ("production" === process.env.NODE_ENV) ? 'css/style-[chunkhash].min.css' : 'css/style.min.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/g,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorOptions: {discardComments: {removeAll: true}},
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["main"]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: false,
            minimize: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            beautify: false,
            comments: false,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = webpack_config;
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй прописать в .babelrc например как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
должно помочь